# geometric buckling for a torus

Tags: probability, geometry, random-walk

Consider for a moment a torus. The torus will have two radii. The large one from above (looking down on the donut) of R and the smaller one r (the cross section of the circular tube)

Imagine a object is generated by at a random point inside the plutonium solution, the object will travel in a random direction for a fixed distance d. Each time it changes direction it has probability Pcap of being captured.

What is the probability that the object will be able to bounce around inside the torus and then escape from the torus without being captured.

Secondly what is the probability that the object will fly out of the torus and then re-enter it by flying through the hole in the "donut".

This question relates to the geometric buckling of a nuclear reactor, if we assume that the capture of the neutron in the plutonium nitrate solution has a chance "Q" per capture to generate n new neutrons. Then what will the neutron flux distribution be inside the torus ?

If you will a object with a fissile solution such as plutonium nitrate this it is possible to create a homogenous nuclear reactor, for spheres, cylinders, cubes and other boxes the equations have been worked out and published years ago.

Comment: This is a very hard question as to calculate it accurately will require a distribution of the likely positions and the velocities of neutrons across the smaller circular cross-section. Depending on the forces, this will also make densities of the solution vary and consequential upon that the distribution of probabilities of impact will vary across the cross-section. If we assume (incorrectly) that the probable position of the neutron is equally distributed through the smaller circle cross-section then mathematically you still have a very hard problem.

Comment: Then, more mathematically speaking you are roughly asking for the probability that a random walk of on average $\frac{1}{Pcap}$ number of steps of length $d$ will leave a Torus of radius $R,r$. Since this is a maths site (and many users shy away from applied maths you might have more success giving the purely mathematical part of it more prominence in your question and demoting the background to a footnote for those who may be interested.

Comment: Thanks "Producer of BS", I will reduce the background of the question. I thought that an applied question was more interesting than a pure maths question. But as I am totally new here I will trust your judgement over my own.

Comment: I think if you leave it as it is others will propose to move it to a physics site (which may be no bad thing as you may actually have more luck there). But it is often considered bad form to cross-post on both.

Comment: Dear Producer of BS, well thanks for being so welcoming to me. Please pat yourself on the back for being the first person to welcome me here. I have no problem with the question being sent to a physics site, but I understand that it is poor form to post in multiple and related locations the same content.